# sql server trigger referencing last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I want to write a trigger in SQL Server to insert 2 rows into `table2` when a row is inserted into `table1`. I want to use a column value from `table1`.

So my trigger looks like this

```
create trigger triggername on table1
as
begin
insert into
insert into
end
```

How do I get the value of any column from the last inserted row (the row insertion which fires the trigger). I.e. the equivalent of 'referencing row' in oracle

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 6):

Triggers in SQL Server fire per statement not per row. There are two pseudo tables `inserted` and `deleted` that you can use (for an `insert` trigger the only one of interest is `inserted`)

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTrigger ON Table1
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO Table2 
SELECT * from inserted /*This will contain multiple rows if it is a multi-row insert*/
```

Answer (score 0):

hi
i have the solution myself. i missed the alias

select @patient_no=fldL1BasCode from inserted

should be

select @patient_no=i.fldL1BasCode from inserted i

Comment: nice to give update, but try to write your updates as Edits to your question, or as Comments to response you received...